# Calculate time difference in hh:mm:ss with simple javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have two input field for the time start and time end and there is another field for the difference which is the Call Duration. I want the result on the field to be in this format = 00:21:03

```
<div class="inline_divider">
  <label for="form_qa_startcall" class="qaw_form_label3">Start of Call</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_qa_startcall" class="qaw_form_input3" placeholder="eg. 11:36:47 PM" maxlength="11">
</div>
<div class="inline_divider">
  <label for="form_qa_endcall" class="qaw_form_label3">End of Call</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_qa_endcall" class="qaw_form_input3" placeholder="eg. 11:46:47 PM" maxlength="11">
</div>
<div class="inline_divider">
  <label for="form_qa_callduration" class="qaw_form_label3">Call Duration</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_qa_callduration" class="qaw_form_input3" placeholder="eg. 00:01:10" maxlength="8">
</div>
```

I am having a hardtime getting the result due to the "AM/PM" formatting.
I have found a similar question like this but he is using "momentjs". As much as possible, I don't want to use any plugins, just a plain javascript or from jquery will do. This is the code I got working, I am getting the result (0:21:3) but I need it to be two digits for hours, minutes, and seconds (00:21:03).

```
$("#form_qa_endcall").on('keyup',function(){
  var callStart = $('#form_qa_startcall').val();
  var callEnd = $('#form_qa_endcall').val();
  var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + callStart);
  var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + callEnd);

    function datediff(fromDate,toDate,interval) {
        var second=1000, minute=second*60, hour=minute*60, day=hour*24, week=day*7;
        fromDate = new Date(fromDate);
        toDate = new Date(toDate);
        var timediff = toDate - fromDate;

        if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN;
        switch (interval) {
            case "years": return toDate.getFullYear() - fromDate.getFullYear();
            case "months": return (
                ( toDate.getFullYear() * 12 + toDate.getMonth() )
                - 
                ( fromDate.getFullYear() * 12 + fromDate.getMonth() )
            );
            case "weeks"  : return Math.floor(timediff / week);
            case "days"   : return Math.floor(timediff / day);
            case "hours"  : return Math.floor(timediff / hour);
            case "minutes": return Math.floor(timediff / minute);
            case "seconds": return Math.floor(timediff / second);
            default: return undefined;
        }
    }
    var seco = datediff(timeStart, timeEnd, 'seconds') % 60;
    var minu = datediff(timeStart, timeEnd, 'minutes') % 60;
    var hour = datediff(timeStart, timeEnd, 'hours');

    $('#form_qa_callduration').val(hour + ":" + minu + ":" + seco);
});
```

Comment: Please show the HTML and code you have tried with.

Comment: `new Date(new Date() - new Date() ).toISOString().split("T")[1].split(".")[0]`

Comment: the above "middle dates" should be the old and new date values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this code:

```js
function diff(a, b) {
    function toTime(a) {  
        return Date.parse('1970-01-01 ' + a.substr(0,8)) / 1000
             + (a.includes('PM') && (12*60*60));
    }
    var d = toTime(b) - toTime(a);
    return d >= 0 ? new Date(0,0,0,0,0,d).toTimeString().substr(0,8) : '';
}

$('.qaw_form_input3').on('input', function () {
    $('#form_qa_callduration').val( 
        diff($('#form_qa_startcall').val(), $('#form_qa_endcall').val()));
}).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline_divider">
  <label for="form_qa_startcall" class="qaw_form_label3">Start of Call</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_qa_startcall" class="qaw_form_input3" placeholder="eg. 11:36:47 PM" maxlength="11">
</div>
<div class="inline_divider">
  <label for="form_qa_endcall" class="qaw_form_label3">End of Call</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_qa_endcall" class="qaw_form_input3" placeholder="eg. 11:46:47 PM" maxlength="11">
</div>
<div class="inline_divider">
  <label for="form_qa_callduration" class="qaw_form_label3">Call Duration</label>
  <input type="text" id="form_qa_callduration" class="qaw_form_input3" placeholder="eg. 00:01:10" maxlength="8" readonly>
</div>
```

As the duration will be updated by changes to the other two input values, it would be a good idea to make the duration input read-only, by adding the `readonly` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. It's now working. about the input for the call duration, originally they want to manually put the difference but yesterday they want to make it automatic calculations so I may have to make it readonly today. :)

Comment: Users and their (always changing) requirements: we all know what a challenge that can be for our patience ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get it as strings, you can roughly do the following.

```js
var str1 = "11:31:51 AM";
var str2 = "11:52:54 AM";

str1 = str1.split(':');
str2 = str2.split(':');

if(str1[2].split(' ').pop() != str2[2].split(' ').pop()) { // one is AM other is PM
   str1[0] = parseInt(str1[0])+12;
}

var finalStr = m(str1[0], str2[0])+":"+m(str1[1], str2[1])+":"+m(str1[2], str2[2]);

console.log(finalStr);

function m(n1,n2) {
  return Math.abs(parseInt(n1)-parseInt(n2));
}
```