# How to calculate time difference using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code for calculating time difference and it works well. I need to change the method (actually I added one more method in certain condition). The method that I added in a condition when the textbox has value `Istirahat`, and then I need to change the method to the time difference that I made minus one hour.

I think it will be confusing to see my explanation without the code.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $time1 = $("#start");
    var $time2 = $("#end");
    var $diff = $("#jam_total");

    function updateHours() {   
        var dtStart = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time1.val());
        var dtEnd = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time2.val());
        var stats1 = $("#status_check").val();

        if(stats1!='ISTIRAHAT') {
            var diff = ((dtEnd - dtStart)) / 1000;
        } else if(stats1!='TANPA ISTIRAHAT') {
            var diff = ((((dtEnd - dtStart)) / 1000) - 1);
        }
        var totalTime = 0;

        if (diff > 60*60*12) {
            totalTime = formatDate(60*60*12);
        } else {
            totalTime = formatDate(diff);
        }

        $diff.val(totalTime);
    }

    function formatDate(diff) {
        var hours = parseInt(diff / 3600) % 24;
        var minutes = parseInt(diff / 60) % 60;
        var seconds = diff % 60;

        return (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes);
    }

    $("#option2").on("change", function() {
        if($time1.val() && $time2.val()) {
            updateHours();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="time" id="start" name="logintime"/>
<input type="time" id="end"name="logouttime" />
<br /><br />
<select name="option2" id="option2" onchange="Choose1(this)" style="float:left">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="istirahat">istirahat</option>
    <option value="tanpa istirahat">tanpa istirahat</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="status_check" size="8" readonly="readonly" id="status_check" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
<br /><br />
Total: <input type="text" id="jam_total" type="text" name="jam_total" size="18" readonly="readonly">
<br /><br />
<script>
function Choose1(data) {
    document.getElementById("status_check").value = data.value;
}
</script>
```

Try to check the jQuery function at the code like this:

```
else if (stats1 != 'TANPA ISTIRAHAT') {
    var diff = ((((dtEnd - dtStart)) / 1000) - 1);
}
```

`var diff = (((dtEnd - dtStart)) / 1000) - 1)` is what I mean, that code won't work perfectly like I want. What I want is like this:

Please check the code inside if `var diff = ((dtEnd - dtStart)) / 1000;` I want the result of this code to be minus one hour.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43192439/4229270

Comment: Did not understand the issue here. What exactly is not working ?

Comment: the code inside the `if else condition`.
i want to make while condition {TANPA ISTIRAHAT} the function will do the function for calculate the time but it need to minus one hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is one thing wrong, you need to set `stats1` to `UpperCase`, otherwise you can't compare correct. Second thing is you are calculating time over seconds, you should minus `60*60` (3600 to minus 1 hours).

```
function updateHours(){   
    var dtStart = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time1.val());
    var dtEnd = new Date("7/20/2015 " + $time2.val());
        var stats1 = $("#status_check").val().toUpperCase(); 
// if you don't add toUpperCase, istirahat won't be equal to ISTIRAHAT so everytime..
// first if block will be executed
   if(stats1!='ISTIRAHAT'){
        var diff = ((dtEnd - dtStart)) / 1000;
         }
   else if(stats1!='TANPA ISTIRAHAT'){

        var diff = ((((dtEnd - dtStart)) / 1000) - 3600); // and you should minus 3600
         }
    var totalTime = 0;

    if (diff > 60*60*12) {
        totalTime = formatDate(60*60*12);
        ;
    } else {
        totalTime = formatDate(diff);
    }

    $diff.val(totalTime);

}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzvgzhok/15/)

Hope helps,

Comment: thx @Berkay.
for calculating time i need to do use time format for doing the calculate right?

Comment: Sure, its up to you. @MinervazMine